# Getting Xpath when clicking on element in a Visual Basic webbrowser control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xpath, basic

I am trying to write a visual basic application to retrieve xpaths from html pages. What I would like to do is have a page load in the web browser, click on any given element on the web page, and have the xpath of that element stored in a variable.

I have been searching the web for 2 days but can not find anything. How can this be done?

I have a basic understanding of VB. I'm just not sure what the code for the onclick event would be.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnBeforeNavigate event and return the URL property

In Access VBA:

Assuming your WebBrowser object is called WebBrowser6

```
Private Sub WebBrowser6_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
        MsgBox (URL)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent code using four spaces, this will improve the formatting by placing code in a box